# How to plot these histograms next to each other

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, histogram

I want to take a look onto data distribution. Problem is I want to make loop that displays each dataframe column separately. With this approach every column's histogram is plotted on one graphical area.

```py
for x in df.columns.to_list():
  df[x].hist(bins=120)
```

[image: histogram_image]

How to divide these histograms to separated images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having sample data with 3 columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5], 
     'col2': [1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 5], 
     'col3': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df
```

[image]

You can use subplots from matplotlib to see each column on separate histogram:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(df.columns), figsize=(8,12))
i=0

for x in df.columns.to_list():
    axs[i].hist(df[x], bins=10)
    i=i+1
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice approach, but still plots are printed on one image. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, understood - just change the loop to:  
`for x in df.columns.to_list():  
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))   
 plt.hist(df[x], bins=10)` in this case each subplot is created inside single loop run so you will get 3 separate images

Answer (score 0):

Why not just
`df.hist(bins=120)`
?
No need to go through the loop.

Comment: then how you separate them into different images?

Comment: Yes, works didn't figure it out, but there's one problem with that. Everything is so small I can't see nothing. Second thing, everything is on one image.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Each column normally is on a different axis object if you do this approach

Comment: @D4w1d you could use matplotlib (the  plotting framework behind the hist function) to do this. First create the object, then plot it on there. annabednarska already gives quite a good answer on how to do this

Comment: @lcdumort you have a share axis option when doing subplots, so the plots share the x axis, y axis or both